# TS file value in ngIf condition

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

How can I get a value from ts file into a ngIf condition in HTML file?
I've tried it with or without the curly brackets, but it doesn't seem to work.
The sender_id is of the number type. Thanks in advance!

.html file

```
*ngIf="item.Sender_ID != {{sender_id}}"
```

ts.file

```
this.api.getStaffDetailsByUsername(this.username).subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res)
      this.department = res[0].Departament;
      this.sender_id = res[0].Staff_ID;
```

Comment: Is the `.ts` file an angular component ? and the `.html` is components template ?

Comment: it should be just `*ngIf="item.Sender_ID != sender_id"`. inside of `[...]` and `*...` everything is an expression, not a string. so interpolation is not needed

Answer (score 0):

As soon as a field is declared as public in the ts file (this is the default case if not # or private or protected is used) the field is available in the html code as well. Only outside of expression "{{ .. }}" is needed. In the *ngIf Directive it is available directly as item is too.